# How to add webhook in clickfunnel. it is not accepting my webhook url

Tags: php, webhooks

For Adding Webhook in Testoptin I followed the below steps with screenshot links you can check.

- I selected the optin first.
- Then I clicked Settings.
- I Selected the manage webhook in order to create a new webhook as shared by clickfunnel Video for wetting up webhook. see the screenshot below.
- I got the option to create a Webhook
- When I fill the form and subtmitted I got this. https://prnt.sc/glbj1o
- I am adding the url Here. https://prnt.sc/glbj1o

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the directories

funnel_webhooks/test

To your web server root. Click funnel hits that path before it adds a new web hook URL.

Comment: can you give us an example of contact_update/create events handling. What would be the endpoint for this?

Comment: CF was giving 404 error on the URL and creating the directory totally worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: SOLUTION: I mentioned this two different times to my developer, and he kept telling me that wouldn't make any difference. We are using asp.net. Finally, he merely created this directory / endpoint. Presto, it worked! Apparently, ClickFunnels does a test to see if this URL is present, then it added the webhook. This is very strange. I've never seen a webhook with this weird test before.

Answer (score 1):

1. Upload your PHP file on server.
2. confirm the file by visiting the URL.
3. Check the URL path in CF webhook field (might be typo mistakes in URL)
4. add 'funnel_webhooks/test' directory on your base domain
5. Try to use HTTPS version of webhook URL.
6. Try www and without www versions in field.
7. Sometime CF give 404 error for newly uploaded file on server.